# We've got at least 26 generic i.imgur.com image links that might break on May 15, 2023; should/could they be updated to i.stack.imgur.com?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Below the Math SE meta question [Imgur's "old, unused, and inactive content"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35685/284619)

> Imgur plans to change its Terms of Service on May 15, 2023. Part of this will be the removal of "old, unused, and inactive content".
>
> Many of the images on Stack Exchange have imgur links. What will happen to those?

a comment says:

> We have [1,970 generic imgur images](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3ai.imgur.com&searchOn=3) subject to this (i.e. which don't don't use SE's corporate stack interface stack.imgur.com).

Astronomy SE has [26 posts](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3ai.imgur.com&searchOn=3) with generic `i.imgur.com` links, many are excellent, well received answers.

**Question:** We've got at least 26 generic i.imgur.com image links that might break on May 15, 2023; should/could they be updated to i.stack.imgur.com? Is there a way to update or convert these without necessarily bumping all to the active queue (not that that would be a bad thing necessarily)

Comment: also asked in [space](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3058/12102)

Answer (score 3):

**Final Update** (29-05-2023): Updated the links

Thank you for writing this. I was about the write the same thing yesterday until my computer started to act weird.

There are two ways we can proceed:

1. Making a meta post and sharing the images there
2. Fixing the posts manually

The former method is followed where the number of posts is too many ([ELU meta followed this approach](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/backing-up-i-imgur-com-images-that-may-be-at-risk-due-to-their-new-tos?cb=1)) while latter method can be followed where number of such posts is not that many (or) the traffic is way less ([Anime & Manga meta followed this approach](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/non-stacks-imgur-images-may-disappear-soon-help-us-migrate-them-to-stacks-img?cb=1)). Since the number of posts is not too many, we can proceed with approach #2 and if you noticed, I have already started this activity although I am doing it in batches to avoid spamming the homepage.

I have used [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/1743757/2119851/top-posts-with-non-stack-imgur-images-order-by-of-views) which returned 39 posts. I invite everyone to help fix the remaining posts (active owner of the posts can make the changes -- there are two posts from @uhoh and 7 posts from our mod @HDE 226868). Please update the list here once it is done.

Posts fixed *by me*:

1. [Is this photocomposition of Andromeda's galaxy and the Moon accurate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23378/is-this-photocomposition-of-andromedas-galaxy-and-the-moon-accurate)
2. [How to deal with shifting CCD bias (zero exposure) levels?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/how-to-deal-with-shifting-ccd-bias-zero-exposure-levels)
3. [Why aren't concentrated solar power plants use for astronomical observations of some type?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48626/why-arent-concentrated-solar-power-plants-use-for-astronomical-observations-of)
4. [Why can't moon light (reflected sun light) turn the sky blue?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/why-cant-moon-light-reflected-sun-light-turn-the-sky-blue/14111#14111)
5. [Is it possible for planetary rings to be perpendicular (or near perpendicular) to the planet's orbit around the host star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40801/is-it-possible-for-planetary-rings-to-be-perpendicular-or-near-perpendicular-t)
6. [Why does this twilight sky flat field have a grid of dark pixels?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/why-does-this-twilight-sky-flat-field-have-a-grid-of-dark-pixels)
7. [Ionization Fraction of Helium in alternate, He dominated early universe](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20517/ionization-fraction-of-helium-in-alternate-he-dominated-early-universe/20529#20529)
8. [What do these coordinates mean: MW - VP101 3° 12' 43.2'' S 5° 12' 39.6'' W?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/what-do-these-coordinates-mean-mw-vp101-3-12-43-2-s-5-12-39-6-w)
9. ["What was that spot in the sky?" - How to identify satellites](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/what-was-that-spot-in-the-sky-how-to-identify-satellites)
10. [Why did they decide to hit Dimorphos in the retrograde direction rather than prograde; was it a "coin-toss" or were there implications for observing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50738/why-did-they-decide-to-hit-dimorphos-in-the-retrograde-direction-rather-than-pro/50742#50742)
11. [If light has no mass, why is it affected by gravity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/if-light-has-no-mass-why-is-it-affected-by-gravity/29150#29150)
12. [What caused the “rake marks” in moon photos?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51987/what-caused-the-rake-marks-in-moon-photos)
13. [Code for getting the pixel coordinates of an object with known RA DEC not working](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/code-for-getting-the-pixel-coordinates-of-an-object-with-known-ra-dec-not-workin)
14. [Exoplanet radius density relation according to NASA exoplanet archive](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27795/exoplanet-radius-density-relation-according-to-nasa-exoplanet-archive)
15. [Is there a significant temperature difference on the moon from apogee to perigee or vice-versa?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26387/is-there-a-significant-temperature-difference-on-the-moon-from-apogee-to-perigee)
16. [On a log-log plot of surface gravity to planet mass, what is the meaning of the y-intercept?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/on-a-log-log-plot-of-surface-gravity-to-planet-mass-what-is-the-meaning-of-the)
17. [Does the earth spiral around the sun's movement/motion path?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40726/does-the-earth-spiral-around-the-suns-movement-motion-path) (non available Imgur images were removed)

---

Below posts couldn't be fixed due to Image/GIF too large

1. [Does the relative motion between planets other than Venus and Earth form shapes such as the Flower of Venus?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26078/does-the-relative-motion-between-planets-other-than-venus-and-earth-form-shapes)
2. [What is this cluster of light trails captured on long exposure images?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50190/what-is-this-cluster-of-light-trails-captured-on-long-exposure-images)

---

Below posts wasn't fixed due to discrepancy in the images (Imgur hyperlinks didn't coincided with the stack images) or it is embedded text hyperlinks:

1. [Problem with Dobsonian reflector telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11278/problem-with-dobsonian-reflector-telescope/11293#11293)
2. [Why don't we have 2 Summers and 2 Winters?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/why-dont-we-have-2-summers-and-2-winters/1189#1189)
3. [Exactly how elliptical is Mercury's orbit, visually, without exaggeration?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/exactly-how-elliptical-is-mercurys-orbit-visually-without-exaggeration/19140#19140)
4. [How does gravity affect a physical clock?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/how-does-gravity-affect-a-physical-clock/43790#43790)
5. [2017 Eclipse intersection with I-95](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/2017-eclipse-intersection-with-i-95/21979#21979)
6. [How much of carbon, sodium, silicon, and magnesium does the Sun have?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/how-much-of-carbon-sodium-silicon-and-magnesium-does-the-sun-have/20347#20347)
7. [Rendering asteroid orientation as seen from Earth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29575/rendering-asteroid-orientation-as-seen-from-earth)